# Java WordLadder Program

Tags: java, time-limit-exceeded, edit-distance

I wrote a program that calculates the minimum number of rungs of a "word ladder" between a starting word and an ending word. The function `minlinks()` takes in 3 arguments: a list which acts as a dictionary, a starting word, and an ending word. It returns an `int[]` of two values; the first is minimum number of links in the word ladder, the second is the number of paths with said number of links.

Example of a word ladder:

> words = [rain, ruin, gain, grin, grit, main, pain, pair, pail, mail] 
>   from = sail  to = ruip
>
> Returns: [6, 2]
>
> There are two links of length six and no shorter links.
>
> sail mail main rain ruin ruip
>    sail pail pain rain ruin ruip

As written, the program works. However, as someone new to coding in Java, I would appreciate others commenting on the coding style. Also, I included a test case in the main method which runs in about 4 seconds on my computer, which is too slow. Is there any way to optimize this program to make it run faster?

```
import java.util.*;
public class WordLinksMin {

    // Helper method, returns true if two words are one letter away from each other.
    public boolean isStep(String from, String s) {
        if (from.length() != s.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        int differences = 0;
        for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < from.length(); charIndex++) {
            if (from.charAt(charIndex) != s.charAt(charIndex)) {
                differences++;
            }
            if(differences > 1) break;
        }
        return (differences == 1);
    }

    // given an array of words (our "dictionary"), the starting word and the ending word. find the minimum number of links between start and end using the given dictionary.
    // function returns int[] array {min number of links, number of paths with min number of links}
    public int[] minLinks(String[] words, String start, String end) {
        int firstFindSize = 0;
        int[] result = new int[2];
        // Convert String[] into a HashSet.
        List < String > myWordList = new ArrayList < String > (Arrays.asList(words));
        Set < ArrayDeque < String >> allStacks = new HashSet < ArrayDeque < String >> ();
        if (myWordList.size() == 0) return result;
        // We will implement BFS with a stack of queues
        ArrayDeque < ArrayDeque < String >> wordQueue = new ArrayDeque < ArrayDeque < String >> (); //one queue of stacks to track nodes visited
        // initialize the parent node, which is a stack containing starting word.
        ArrayDeque < String > startStack = new ArrayDeque < String > ();
        startStack.push(start);
        wordQueue.add(startStack);
        // we act differently in while loop based on whether we have already found a path from start to end
        boolean firstFind = true;

        while (!wordQueue.isEmpty()) {

            ArrayDeque < String > currentStack = wordQueue.pop();

            String currentWord = currentStack.peek();
            if (isStep(currentWord, end) && currentStack.size() >= 2 && firstFind) { //no direct link
                currentStack.push(end);
                allStacks.add(currentStack);
                firstFind = false; //after finding first stack, we know the stack size we must look for, for any other path of the same length.
                firstFindSize = currentStack.size();
                //System.out.println((firstFindSize));
                //System.out.println("before ff");
                //System.out.println(currentStack);

            } else if (isStep(currentWord, end) && currentStack.size() == firstFindSize - 1 && !firstFind) {
                currentStack.push(end);
                //System.out.println("not ff");
                //System.out.println(currentStack);
                allStacks.add(currentStack);
            }

            if (firstFind) {
                for (String word: myWordList) {
                    if (isStep(currentWord, word) && !currentStack.contains(word)) {
                        ArrayDeque < String > wordStack = new ArrayDeque < String > (currentStack);
                        wordStack.push(word);
                        wordQueue.add(wordStack);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        result[1] = allStacks.size();
        result[0] = firstFindSize;
        System.out.printf("%d %d", result[0], result[1]);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordLinksMin a = new WordLinksMin();
        String[] b = {
                "abcde", "abcda", "abcdb", "abcdc", "abcdd", "abcdf", "abcdg", "abcdh", "abcdi", "abcdj", "abcdk", "obcda", "obcdb", "obcdc", "obcdd", "obcdf", "obcdg", "obcdh", "obcdi", "obcdj", "obcdk", "obcdm", "obadm", "obbdm", "obddm", "obedm", "obfdm", "obgdm", "obhdm", "obidm", "objdm", "obkdm", "okadm", "okbdm", "okddm", "okedm", "okfdm", "okgdm", "okhdm", "okidm", "okjdm", "okkdm", "okodm", "okokm" 
        };
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(a.minLinks(b, "abode","okoko"));
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = (endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println(duration);
        //      for (List<String> list : a.listOfPaths){
        //          for (String s : list) {
        //              System.out.print(s+" ");
        //          }
        //          System.out.println();
        //      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. About the algorithm itself. I do not fully understand the algorithm you are using now, but it looks pretty strange(a bfs with a stack of queues?) and, as you have said, it is inefficient. So let's redesign it:

   - Let's start with a clear problem statement in terms of graphs: given a graph where each node corresponds to a word and there is a bidirectional edge between two nodes iff the words differ in exactly one letter, find the shortest path between two nodes and the number of shortest paths.
   - Before running the breadth-first search, let's build the graph explicitly and forget about the words. We can do by simply checking each pairs of words as you do it now.
   - Now let's run a BFS on this graph and get the length of the shortest path.
   - How to find the number of such paths? We have the following formula: `f(v) = sum f(u) for all u such that dist[u] = dist[v] - 1` and `f(start) = 1`. We can compute it efficiently using memoization.
   - The time complexity is `O(len * N ^ 2)`, where `len` is the length of the words and `N` is their number. It should be very fast for such a small dictionary if implemented properly.
2. The `minLinks` method seems too big to me. Taking into account a new algorithm described in 1., I'd do it this way:

   - Create three separate methods: one for building the graph, another one for running the breadth-first search and the last one for counting the number of shortest path.
   - We can go even further and create a separate graph class so that this class has to only build an appropriate graph. It is definitely good for code reuse and makes a good sense from the design point of view: a graph and breadth-first search is a very general notion and it has almost nothing to do with words.

Summary: both 1. and 2. express the same idea(from different point of views): we can represent this problem as a graph problem using standard graph concepts and algorithms and separate it from words to achieve better performance and better design.

Comment: thank you! The answer is pretty comprehensive and tells me what I need to know.